# Find first index smaller than list value (Isabelle)

Tags: list, set, min, isabelle

Consider a set, say `S = {7,0,4}`, then `sorted_list_of_set(S) = [0,4,7]`, call that list `L`.  I want to return the smallest index,`j`, of `L` such that `j < L!j`, call that `m`. I suspect that requires building a set `A = {j : j < L!j}` then `m = min(A)`, however I'm unsure how the .thy file `Set` handles this (I don't understand how membership and "collect" work yet).

Comment: Why not iterate over the indices and stop at the first one such that `j < L ! j`. Something along the lines of: `f curr_idx (a # xs) = (if curr_idx < a then curr_idx else f (Suc curr_idx) xs`

Comment: Anyway instead of collect, you do know that  `Min {j. j < L!j}` works right?

Comment: @Mathias Fleury: `Min` needs finiteness though. `Inf {j. j < L ! j}` and `LEAST j. j < L ! j` should work though, although I would really add the requirement `j < length L` for convenience.

Comment: Good point. Actually it even worse, because it is not defined otherwise (`0 < [] ! 0` is undefined, not false)